# Compiler not executing program in codeblock

Tags: c, codeblocks

I was writing a code for printing the longest word in string entered by me.
But the program is not executing and am getting a error message to close the program.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
   char my_str[] = "in this program we will find the longest keyword used so 
   that we can";


int longest = 0; 
char word[20];      
char longestWord[20]; 

int i = 0, j;

while(my_str[i]!='\0'){
    j = 0;
    while(my_str[i]!=' ' && my_str[i]!='\0'){
        word[j++] = my_str[i++];
    }
           word[j] = '\0';
    if (strlen(word) > longest){
        longest = strlen(word);
        strcpy(longestWord, word);
    }

    if (my_str[i] == ' '){
        i++;
    }
}
printf("Longest word: %s\n", longestWord);
printf("Length: %d\n", longest);

return 0;
}
```

Fixed code

Comment: Does it compiling properly ? check the `2nd` argument of `strcpy(longestword,longest);`

Comment: Should `j` be used in the second `while`?

Comment: [strtok](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok).

Answer (score 0):

here is my rewritten code-- answer---`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
   char my_str[] = "in this program we will find the longest keyword used so 
   that we can";


int longest = 0; 
char word[20];      
char longestWord[20]; 

int i = 0, j;

while(my_str[i]!='\0'){
    j = 0;
    while(my_str[i]!=' ' && my_str[i]!='\0'){
        word[j++] = my_str[i++];
    }
           word[j] = '\0';
    if (strlen(word) > longest){
        longest = strlen(word);
        strcpy(longestWord, word);
    }

    if (my_str[i] == ' '){
        i++;
    }
}
printf("Longest word: %s\n", longestWord);
printf("Length: %d\n", longest);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: this code still has some errors (It didn't even compile in my machine). Maybe look at it a little more. Since we answered your problem, there is no need to post the actual correct code btw

Comment: hello sir, but it's running correctly in online compilers.can you help me out in finding? sorry for long delay.being a beginner, I thought that I will never learn to code.

Comment: hello again. It seems the compilation error was only due to the fact that the value of the string `my_str`, as it is written in the code above, occupies two lines, something I failed to see when copy-pasting. That's why it didn't work. When I placed it in on a single line, your program executed perfectly. I am sorry for not being informative enough in my previous comment. You are in fact correct. Don't worry about being a beginner. Everyone has been. Cheers.

Comment: Thanx a lot sir, it was a great help. Thanks for motivation also.Can you help me out, how can I engage myself in live projects which will further help in improving my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't codeblock's error. Your program starts actually running but then it crashes ( due to a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)  ) and windows/codeblock display this "... has stopped working" message.

The actual line that causes the crash is `longest` in line

```
strcpy(longestword,longest);
```

I believe you meant `longestword` there.

Also mind that there are more mistakes to your code both in syntax (read the compiler's warning before executing it) and in logic.

Comment: @AshutoshKumarMishra Mind that this was not the only error of your code, but it was the answer why it crashed. (Also, I have edited a link referring to segmentation faults)